# Send data to rs232/usb-adapter via socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, serial-port

I want to send this hex command block:

```
1B 40 26 0D
```

over a java socket and a proxy (serproxy) to a machine with RS232. I have following code:

```
DataOutputStream outToServer  = new DataOutputStream(this.clientsocket.getOutputStream());
String command5 = "\u001b\u0040\u0026\u240D";
outToServer.writeUTF(command5);
outToServer.flush();
```

Socket and serproxy are correctly configured. Anybody with an idea?

Comment: How did you initialize **clientsocket** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`writeUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) function writes the length of the string before its characters. What you can use is plain write:

```
byte[] bytes = {0x1B, 0x40, ...};
out.write(bytes)
```

Comment: I get an erro with 0xa6 (Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte). Don't I have to use the \u00 syntax?

Comment: 0xA6 has to be cast to byte, `(byte) 0xA6`, because it's out of range (reason being that in Java bytes are signed). The `\uABCD`-thing is only for you to be able to write Unicode characters in source code without fear of the compiler messing it up; not useful right now.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code seems to work fine now. I checked the output with SerialMon. My problem with this rs232 controller seems to be different. Its not answering and preferes to do nothing. I need to check it with an Arduino connected directly. Thanks